# Uneven padding while using AspectRatio in RegionPlot

Tags: regions

When I use the **AspectRatio** option for `RegionPlot`, the padding on the left and right is wider than it is at the top and bottom. Is there a way to equalize this space on all sides of the plot?

```
RegionPlot[Abs[x] < 1 && Abs[y] < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

Comment: You could set PlotRangePadding->None to get no padding on either side.

Answer (score 3):

```
RegionPlot[Abs[x] < 1 && Abs[y] < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRangePadding -> {1, 2}/20]
```

[image]